# gh command not found, even after installation

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, github-cli, linuxbrew

I recently have uninstalled Homebrew, as I don't need it anymore, which I previously have installed Github CLI through. I am using WSL2 to re-install Github CLI using the [official provided script](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md).

I get no error messages during installation process, however, when I go to use the `gh` command, I get the following error:

[image: Terminal output error]

It says it can't find it, where `which gh` clearly shows it is installed on my system, plus the linuxbrew folder doesn't exist anymore.

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated!

**EDIT**: Every time I start a new terminal session, this also happens, if it helps debugging my issue.

[image]

Comment: It looks like linuxbrew added a symlink which is now broken. You can check with `file -h /usr/bin/gh`. If it's a broken symlink, you can safely `unlink` it and try installing `gh` again.

Comment: Are you sure that uninstalling Homebrew (linuxbrew?) should have left you with working installations of programs you have installed with it?

Comment: Nvm, I found the culprit. This line was located in my `~/.profile` file: `eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)`. I just commented it out, and now the `gh` command is working fine, based off the `usr/bin/gh` location.